# pass two arguments into translate()

Tags: python

how do I pass two arguments into translate()? I want to remove digits and punctuation

```
str = str.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

how can I pass string.digits in as well without having to repeat the above line and just change one word?

Comment: string.digits + string.punctuation?????

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `translate` instead of a method more intended for filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate your parameters since they are both strings:

```
string.punctuation + string.digits
```

For example:

```
import string

s = "This is a string with 123456 []!@#$%^& stuff"
s = s.translate(None, string.digits + string.punctuation)
print s
```

This will return

```
This is a string with   stuff
```

If you are curious, the `string.punctuation + string.digits` results in this string being passed to the function:

```
0123456789!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```